# Could not find jarfile:/F:/eclipse-cpp-mars-2-win32-x86_64.zip!/

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

How to solve this problem?It drives me crazy?

[image]

---

Information of the version of eclipse:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build
id: 20160218-0600

Comment: Why are you trying to use `jar:file:/F:/eclipse-cpp-mars-2-win32-x86_64.zip!/` as a software site url?

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually Windows uses `backward \` for path. And Unix based systems use `forward /`. You are using `forward /` for windows path.
2. I would suggest to use website link for additional software installation in eclipse.
3. For manual installation, [Dropins](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started#Dropins) folder is used.

Comment: I am using forward/ on windows 7.But i am in china,the use of website link is unstable.So i download the zip file for installation.

Comment: Fianlly,i choose to download Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.And i copy  plugins and features files into the directory of Eclipse.

Comment: Take a look at [Dropins](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Getting_Started#Dropins). You need to extract files in this folder and restart eclipse.